# Can you emulate a null modem mode in CH341 driver?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver

I've installed a device in a remote location with a serial to USB converter connected to a Raspberry Pi. Due to a series of unfortunate events, it turns out that the instrument should have been connected with a null modem cable and now the Tx and Rx of the RS232 DB9 is the wrong way around.

Is there any way for the Tx and Rx to be swapped in software by changing the driver source? I have been able to build and install the driver module manually, just need to know if and how the CH341 can be configured. (I've seen that some other drivers have a "null modem" configurable block).

Comment: I don't think its gonna work, you can send a custom made wire with rx, tx fixed to use with it.

Comment: No, changing the driver source will not help you.